# jQuery Adding text under images

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, text

I would like some guidance as to how to make the text display underneath my images. Each image must have a text display. I want it to show the next `<img>` when I hit the Next Graphic `<button>`. For some reason it is showing both images side by side then going to the next graphic. Maybe there is something I missed when the code was modified. Below is the jQuery and html. Thank you in advance for your help and guidance.

Create an X/HTML document which displays an initial graphic and a form-like button which displays "Next Graphic".

A visible descriptive paragraph about the graphic.  You may use any graphic that you like.

When the user clicks on the button, a different graphic will display with a different descriptive paragraph.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#imgNext").click(function() {
         var $curr = $('.slideshow img:visible'),
         $next = ($curr.next().length) ? $curr.next() : $('.slideshow img').first();
         $next.css('z-index',2).fadeIn('slow', function() {
         $curr.hide().css('z-index',0);
         $next.css('z-index',1);
        });
    });

});
</script>

<div id ="text_slider">

<div/>
<button src="spi/spi2.jpg" width="50" height="50" id="imgNext">Next Graphic</button>
<br />
<div class="slideshow">
    <img class="slider_image" id="1" src="spi/spi1.jpg">
    <p>This is South Padre Island Texas. I grew up going every summer since I can remember.</p>

    <img class="slider_image" id="2" src="spi/spi2.jpg">
    <p>This is the beautiful beaches of South Padre Island. </p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Better if you can add a demo what you actually is looking for.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/robertelias/2po57hjd/ has my demo of what it looks like. I needed to display my image with a text under neath for each image. I will send you a pm

Comment: are you using any plugin for the slideshow?

Comment: No plugin. I am trying to just use jquery however I am not able to figure out a way to do that. I using two images that require a text underneath the images/pics

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [http://captionjs.com/](http://caption.js).

From the instructions:

Insert `<script src="jquery.caption.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` into your code.

Then, add the `CSS`:

Finally, initialize the plugin:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('img.caption').captionjs();
});
```

To actually add a caption:

```
<img src="photo.jpg" data-caption="A wonderful caption for the photo."/>
```

You can also customize the plugin, such as hiding the text when the user hovers over the image, or hiding the text when a user isn't hovering on the image, and putting the caption on the picture, instead of below it.

For example:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('img.caption').captionjs({
        'class_name'      : 'captionjs', // Class name for each <figure>
        'schema'          : true,        // Use schema.org markup (i.e., itemtype, itemprop)
        'mode'            : 'default',   // default | stacked | animated | hide
        'debug_mode'      : false,       // Output debug info to the JS console
        'force_dimensions': true,        // Force the dimensions in case they cannot be detected (e.g., image is not yet painted to viewport)
        'is_responsive'   : false,       // Ensure the figure and image change size when in responsive layout. Requires a container to control responsiveness!
        'inherit_styles'  : false        // Have the caption.js container inherit box-model properties from the original image
    });
});
```

See the webpage for more details.

EDIT: The caption is **part** of the image, so it's much easier to slide it around.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. However, I am wondering how I can use it with my current code with the button? Do I just use what you gave me and add it to my code?

Comment: The parameters require me to use $(document).ready(function() {

Comment: It can work perfectly alongside your code. Just put it in a document ready function, and you're good to go.